# Parse JSON in iphone application with json-framework

Tags: iphone, json, ipad

I am new in iphone development.I am using currency converter in my apps.
I don't have any idea how to parse json with this url  http://www.google.com/calculator?. I want to send my all detail such as quantiy,select currency,to currency  and wants to display the result in label. pls provide any help or any code for me how will i parse this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/):

```
NSString *json = @"{lhs: "2 U.S. dollars",rhs: "89.7988506 Indian rupees",error: "",icc: true}"

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [json JSONValue];

NSString *lhs = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"lhs"];
NSString *rhs = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"rhs"];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/) is the tutorial to help you out...

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.