# Need help parsing JSON on iPhone application

Tags: iphone, json, ipad

i am new in json parsing .I don't know how to send data to server[http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?] by use of textfield according to user input. And whatever result will come by server how will i display that data on my result label .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official feature included in the SDK for parsing JSON. Have a look at the [JSON Framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/). Instructions are at the bottom of the page.

(Also just noticed that you [asked something simliar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992487/parse-json-in-iphone-application-with-json-framework) an hour ago).